# How can I protect my windows host PC when it's added in company AD domain?

Tags: windows-7, networking, privacy

I have a windows 7 PC with Avast Free Antivirus and default windows Firewall.
I need my PC to be registered in my work domain to use network resources.
But I think that it's like giving the keys to the system admin to my computer.
He may know :

- what's in my computer (OS, software, files, documents, etc....)
- which websites I visit

Brief,... I think putting my PC in the work domain is like installing TeamViewer in the background and sys admins can do what ever they want.

I know this is not entirely true. But I'm looking for way for PROTECTING MY PRIVACY as much as possible ;

- should I create a new windows account specific for work ?
- should I set specific firewall rules for that account ?
- should I use proxy like Tor of something else ?
- etc ...
- what could I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... It seems you have some misunderstandings (which I believe may be pretty common misunderstandings).  Let me offer some clarifying details.

It is good to have knowledge, like knowing what the technical capabilities are.  It is good to know what the advantages and disadvantages of certain choices may be.  Therefore, it is good to know what the impacts are of using a variation of Microsoft Windows that supports using the Active Directory security model.

> I know this is not entirely true. But I'm looking for way for PROTECTING MY PRIVACY as much as possible ;

Actually... it IS true.

When your computer is connected to the network (which can include when connected to VPN), he will typically have remote access to your C:

If your computer is reachable by an IP address of 192.0.2.150, then he can visit \192.0.2.150\c$ and see everything on your C:

> He may know :
>   what's in my computer (OS, software, files, documents, etc....)

As for

> which websites I visit

You don't even need to be on the Active Directory domain for that.  If your computer uses their network to send traffic through, he can check the IP destinations of outgoing traffic.  If you're using a VPN to have traffic go through the network, you don't even need to be on-site.  (Note that some VPN configurations have all network traffic go through the VPN, and some don't.  So, not all VPNs cause that effect when you're remote.  Furthermore, at least some VPN software may download some configuration information from the router; none of that has to do with whether you're part of the Active Directory domain or not.)

A totally different approach is that if your computer uses their DNS server, he can see what DNS queries you make.  Again, none of that has to do with whether you're part of the Active Directory domain or not.

Whether that is commonly done with software built into Windows may be another story, but such capabilities definitely exist.  (He might need to obtain extra software, or use functionality built into some of the equipment that is used.)

Even worse than just seeing what websites you visit: The network administrator may be able to see the contents of your "secure" web browsing session.  If you're on an Active Directory domain, then the network administrator can get your computer to follow certain "policies", including installing an HTTPS certificate.  That will enable an HTTPS proxy to perform MITM spying of "secure" web traffic, and your computer will trust the results because your computer will trust the HTTPS certificate of the HTTPS web proxy.

Unlike some of the other "threats" I mention above, this one is actually quite commonly performed.  (The manufacturers of the devices don't advertise this feature as being "MITM attack".  They advertise the feature as "HTTPS proxy" and/or a "deep packet inspection" ("DPI") feature.)

When your computer is installed on the Active Directory domain, that means your computer will trust an Active Directory domain controller's security judgements.  This allows your computer to easily use a Windows account that is stored on the Active Directory domain controller(s).  This also includes your computer checking the domain controller for updated Group Policy settings that your computer will comply with.  Using Group Policy, additional software can be installed.  This can include things like common commercial system monitoring software.  This absolutely includes the ability to install keyboard logging software.  (Hopefully that is done less commonly, but the capability is definitely there.)

In short:

- if you want a computer that is resilient against usage by the outside world, consider a seriously hardened operating system - OpenBSD may be a good choice.
- If you want a computer that is widely recognized as easy to use, then that is the key reason why many people favor using Microsoft Windows.
- If you want a computer that integrates nicely with the company network, including letting the company's technical support be able to make modifications to the computer, then have the computer join the Active Directory domain.

Company policy may require that you utilize that third option.  Whether the company has such a policy that the company requires you to follow is beyond the scope of a discussion about technical capabilities.  It might be true that you *should* give the company such access.  Regardless of whether that is the case, or not, this answer's first paragraph remains true.

> should I create a new windows account specific for work ?

No good.  The "domain computer" (a computer that has "joined the domain") will trust a "domain controller" (which is a name used for a "server" computer that helps provide security on the network).  The domain administrator can just use the accounts that the computer will trust.

> should I set specific firewall rules for that account ?

Not recommended.  You're probably not smart enough to counter all of the types of network traffic that could be used to get into the computer.  And, even if you were, it would be schizophrenic to be saying "I trust the company network" on one hand (when the computer joins the domain), and "I don't trust the company network" on the other hand where you use the firewall to try to break lots of stuff.

If the computer is acting like a proper domain member, then the network administrator can control some aspects of the built-in Windows Firewall.

> should I use proxy like Tor of something else ?

Ineffective.  That may help the network traffic to be encrypted when it leaves your network card.  That wouldn't prevent the domain computer from running some software that your network administrator says that the domain computer can run.

Note that I'm not saying you shouldn't use Tor.  I'm just saying that you should know just what Tor accomplishes, and not have the misunderstanding of thinking that it accomplishes something different.  Tor is designed to protect the contents of network traffic.  Tor is not designed to protect an authorized administrator from seeing what software is running on a machine, or what that software does.  If you want to protect against that capability, I'm simply saying that Tor would be ineffective and providing any protection against that, specifically.

> etc ...
>     what could I do ?

You can do exactly what you did: ask questions, and get educated.  In short, the solution to keeping privacy is to not have the computer joined to the Active Directory domain.  If you are required to have a computer be joined to the Active Directory domain to do certain things, like accessing files, then use another computer (which is not joined to the Active Directory domain) to be doing your more "private" activities.

(Even if you are using your own device, know that the network operators can see some aspects like knowing what Internet sites you connect to.  If you're using your company's network, that means that the company's network operator can see that.  If your device is using a method of directly communicating with a wireless phone company's towers, then it will be the wireless phone company that has that capability.  By the way, the Internet is a giant network of computer networks.  The ability to check/log some details about your network traffic, like destination IP address, is something that can be done by the network operator(s) of *any* computer network that ends up being involved in making your Internet communication work, not necessarily just the first hop.)

> I have a windows 7 PC with Avast Free Antivirus and default windows Firewall.

Know that most Anti-Virus companies are going to want their product to be nicely sellable to people who run company networks.  Therefore, the anti-virus companies will typically *allow* network administrators to have access to see things like what you're asking to allow to remain private.  That is because the software, which enables network operators to have such access, is software that is typically legitimately *authorized*, and therefore Anti-Virus software is likely to permit such software to perform the tasks without interference.  When Anti-Virus software does mistakenly start blocking such tasks, they rapidly get a large number of complaints from network administrators who claim that the Anti-Virus software is breaking critical functionality, and so the Anti-Virus software manufacturer quickly works to fix that "mistake".

Comment: Nice answer sir. OMG. This means that there is no way to keep my privacy at all. It's not just about joining AD as long as I'm using the corp network sys admin can do what ever he wants then. I liked the part where you talked about OpenBSD. If I install it (or any other UNIX/LINUX), does it mean since sys admin doesn't root password I'm pretty safe from file disclosure like ` \192.0.2.150\c$ ` ? Actually if I can't protect my traffic I'd really appreciate if all files (unless shared in some ways) are protected from sys admin intrusion (again in the case of OpenBSD, or Fedora or any Linux) ?