# Could Windows bitlocker disk encryption prevent unauthorized file disclosure in active directory?

Tags: windows, encryption, active-directory

Let's say my laptop is in put in someone's domain (Active directory or network)... From [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1253159/how-can-i-protect-my-windows-host-pc-when-its-added-in-company-ad-domain/1253170#1253170) I understand that there is little to no way I can prevent sys admin or network admin to PWN my PC at will...

But I was thinking about Windows Bitlocker Drive encryption... What if I encrypt my whole drive ? Is my privacy more secure that way ? Could active directory sys admin still see all my files or anything I'm doing on my PC if BitLocker encrypt the whole drive ?

Is there anyway to sandbox my files or parts of my system to protect at best my privacy ?

Comment: Why are you joining your pc with a strange AD?  Bitlocker isn’t going to protect your files but EFS would.  They would have to know your password to access files encrypted by your certificate.  If they forced a password change they would still not have to the files encrypted by the certificate.  So no, Bitlocker wouldn’t be helpful

Comment: @Ramhound NO the AD is not strange. It's work AD. I need to join the AD (or the network) to access resources (Ex : printer, databases, etc...). So with EFS I could get what I want am I correct ? The system admin even though with me joining the network will be able to see my files BUT not open them ? EFS changes files names ?

Comment: No, EFS doesn’t change file names, they just couldn’t access encrypted files without the certificate used to encrypt them.  Please do proper research on Windows EFS before enabling it.

Comment: @Ramhound Okay. Thank you mate. One last thing ; is it at all possible to monitor my PC in a that I'd detect sys admin intrusion (like with an IDS or somtheting ?)